# Issue running Bundler even after updating it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, bundler

I keep getting the below error after running this command on Ubuntu:

```
sudo -u huginn -H bundle install --deployment --without development test
```

This is the error:

```
[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: Line " RAILS_ENV=production" doesn't match format. Bundler cannot continue.
from /home/huginn/huginn/Gemfile:14
-------------------------------------------
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'lib/gemfile_helper.rb')   GemfileHelper.load_dotenv do |dotenv_dir|  #    path dotenv_dir do  # 
-------------------------------------------
```

I have the latest version of bundler

**EDIT: This is my Gemfile:**

```
# Ruby 2.2.2 is the minimum requirement ruby ['2.2.2', RUBY_VERSION].max
# Ensure github repositories are fetched using HTTPS git_source(:github) do     |repo_name|   repo_name =
"#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")  
"https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git" end if
Gem::Version.new(Bundler::VERSION) < Gem::Version.new('2')
# Load vendored dotenv gem and .env file require     File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'lib/gemfile_helper.rb')
GemfileHelper.load_dotenv do |dotenv_dir|   path dotenv_dir do
gem 'dotenv'
gem 'dotenv-rails'   end end
```

Comment: How does your `Gemfile` look like? Please post your Gemfile and the full error message including the stack trace

Comment: How do I access the Gemfile? Sorry if I sound naive. I am really new to this.

Comment: There should be a file named `Gemfile` in the root of your project. Just open it in a text editor and paste its content into your question.

Comment: Just figured out how to paste it and did :) @spickermann